# Implementing generic messaging in C++ using templates

Tags: c++, templates, generics, messaging

I'm trying to implement generic messaging to send messages of generic type between classes in C++, however I am stuck with the generic listener and virtual function calls to handle the messages of various types. The compiler is unable to find the symbols for the virtual handle message function and gives the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "messaging::IMessageListener<int>::handleMessage(int const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for messaging::IMessageListener<int> in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#ifndef MESSAGING_HPP
#define MESSAGING_HPP

#include <vector>

namespace messaging{

template<typename T> class IMessageListener;

template <typename T> class IMessageContext {

    std::vector<IMessageListener<T>* > _listeners;

public:
    template<typename T2>
    void attachListener(IMessageListener<T>* _listener){
        _listeners.push_back(_listener);
    }

    template<typename T2>
    void detach(IMessageListener<T>* _listener){
        _listeners.erase(std::remove(_listeners.begin, _listeners.end(), _listener), _listeners.end());
    }

    template<typename T2>
    void send(const T& _msg){
        typename std::vector<IMessageListener<T>* >::iterator i;
        for(i = _listeners.begin(); i != _listeners.end(); ++i){
            (*i)->handleMessage(_msg);
        }
    } };

template<typename T> class IMessageListener { public:
    virtual void handleMessage(const T&); };

} //namespace messaging

#endif // MESSAGING_HPP
```

And the derived classes:

```
class context : public messaging::IMessageContext<int>
{
public:
    void go(const int &i)
    {
        send<int>(i);
    }
};

class listener : public messaging::IMessageListener<int>
{
public:
    virtual void handleMessage(const int &i){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{
    context c;
    listener l;
    c.attachListener<int>(&l);
    c.go(1234);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided definition for `IMessageListener<T>::handleMessage`:

```
template<typename T> class IMessageListener { public:
    virtual void handleMessage(const T&); 
    //                                  ^
};
```

If you intend to leave it unimplemented, make it pure-virtual:

```
template<typename T> class IMessageListener { public:
    virtual void handleMessage(const T&) = 0;
    //                                   ^^^
};
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i missed that :/

Comment: @Rag: happens, also don't forget about virtual destructor in your interface class